# rails mechanize .click undefined method `click' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I have created a mechanize task in rails. it is very simple

```
task :estimateone => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'

  mechanize = Mechanize.new
  page = mechanize.get('https://www.theurbanlist.com/brisbane/a-list/50-brisbane-cafes-you-should-have-eaten-breakfast-at')
  page.css('ol li a').each do |link|
    link.click
  end

end
```

but I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `click' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x00007ffb4b281830>
/Users/jeremybray/RubymineProjects/OpportunityFinder/lib/tasks/getlead.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:204:in `block in each'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `upto'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/jeremybray/RubymineProjects/OpportunityFinder/lib/tasks/getlead.rake:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jeremybray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As click is a method of Mechanize, you should use your instance of it as the receiver of the click method, not the link, that's a Nokogiri one.

As the [doc](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/Mechanize.html#method-i-click) states, it receives the element, clicks it and returns the fetched page.

Try with:

```
-- snip --
page.css('ol li a').each do |link|
  mechanize.click(link)
end
```

Comment: also, there are so many different docs thanks for sharing these ones

Answer (score 1):

`Page#links_with` will return links, css will return html elements:

```
page.links_with(css: 'ol li a').each do |link|
  link.click
end
```